# Problem with the HttpSession object = request.getSession (); JSP

Tags: java, jsp, java-web-start, netbeans-8

I have struggled with this problem but I don't understand it. Here is the stack trace:

[image: Stack trace]

This is my radio button:

[image: Radio button]

Here I assign a variable for each of the radio button groups that I have, and create an object for each of the variables:

[image: Assignment]

I use a variable to store what comes from the form and assign the value to it:

[image: Use variable]

However, when I go to my third form and click on submit, the last page that processes the data shows me this error that only appears in that line, since the previous ones do collect the data:

[image: Error]

Comment: please embed images inside the question, and more importantly, don't post code using images

Comment: Your question is difficult to follow because there are multiple instances of the same stack trace, and several small snippets of code. Could you modify your code to show a single stack trace, and your entire JSP? If the code is too long and/or too complex it is incumbent on you to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question instead. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and update your question to post your code as text.

Comment: It would be much easier, if your code wouldn't be an image. In the editor is an easy possibility to paste and format your code.